# Generics in C# with OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, generics, oledb

Rather than maintaining a few different database access layers for OleDbConnection, MySqlConnection, OdbcConnection, and Db2Connection, I was trying to figure out a way to use generics. However, I get an error when I try to compile the code, I get errors when I try to access the class's methods or properties.

```
public class DatabaseConnector<CONNECTION> {
    private CONNECTION connection = default(CONNECTION);
    public bool IsConnected {
        get {
            return (
                this.connection != null &&
                // error on connection.State on the following two lines
                this.connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed &&
                this.connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Broken
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way around this? Or perhaps another class that can handle the many versions?

Comment: They already have this: just use the base class for all those, DbConnection. You only have to reference the particular implementation when you create the intial connection object, after that just always use DbXXX types and your code will work across all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for constraints:

```
public class DatabaseConnector<TConnection> where TConnection : DbConnection, new() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `where` in your class definition:

```
 class DatabaseConnector<CONNECTION> where CONNECTION: DbConnection
```

Like this you will be able to use the methods defined in the common class.

you will need after that to make a similar class for command and all the other functions that you need.

Answer (score 0):

That fixed it! It never occurred to me to use interfaces.

```
public class DatabaseConnector<CN, TRANS, CMD, DA, PARAM>
    where CN:IDbConnection
    where TRANS:IDbTransaction
    where CMD:IDbCommand
    where DA:IDbDataAdapter
    where PARAM:IDbDataParameter
```